# Is there anyway to use expressJs with HapiJs in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hapi.js

I have an old application using HapiJs Framework,
my question is, if i can use express for routing with HapiJs for future work?

Comment: Why would you do this? Hapi already has built in support for routing: https://hapijs.com/tutorials/routing

Answer (score 0):

Express and Hapi are two different frameworks. Best way is to rewrite your old application in Express